# index on "_id" in couchdb exists by default?

Tags: javascript, indexing, view, couchdb, nosql

It seems an index is created only when a view is defined, is it true for the "_id" field of each document?
do I have to create a view like this: function(doc) { emit(doc._id,null);} ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Probably the built-in index

```
/db/_all_docs
```

is what you're looking for. It has the `_id` as key and the revision as value. See the [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html) for details.

Comment: it is, documentation says it's a view --> it is indexed. thanks a lot